# M'entrainer (avec lui / derrière lui)

Tags: expressions, prépositions

> A m’entraine.
>
> A m’entraine **avec lui**.
>
> A m’entraine **derrière lui**.

Je me demande s'il est possible d'ajouter *avec lui* ou *derrière lui* dans cette phrase. Est-ce que ce sera redondant ? En tout cas, je ne trouve pas beaucoup d'exemples sur *Google*.

Antidote, la définition d'*entrainer* :

> Faire aller **avec soi** ou **derrière soi**, par la force physique. *Le
> torrent entraina le canot.*

Comment: D'où vient la définition? Le Larousse me semble plus précis: 1. Traîner quelque chose ou quelqu'un avec soi, derrière soi, les emporter avec soi en parlant de quelque chose ou de quelqu'un en mouvement : Le vase tomba en entraînant les bibelots posés à côté.
A m'entraine derrière lui, mais pas A m'entraine avec lui. A moins qu'il y ait A, toi et une autre personne.

Comment: @Lambie *A m'entraîne avec lui* est tout à fait possible et courant sans qu'il y ait besoin d'un tiers.

Comment: Là on n'est pas d'accord. Du point de vue logique. Si A m'entraine, bien sûr que c'est "avec lui* à moins que cela soit avec quelqu'un d'autre. avec lui peut se lire comme étant redondant.

Comment: @Lambie *Avec lui* n'est pas spécialement redondant, tu viens d'ailleurs de montrer qu'il ne suffit pas à lever l'ambiguïté de la phrase. On ne sait même pas si A est une personne, un objet, une idée, un élément naturel (le vent, le courant, etc.)

Comment: C'est une lecture alternative, **peut se lire comme redondant n'est pas se lit.

Comment: @Lambie Alors, je ne comprends pas ce que tu veux dire par *A m'entraine derrière lui, mais pas A m'entraine avec lui*. Pour moi, la phrase *A m'entraîne avec lui* est plus idiomatique et logique que *A m'entraîne derrière lui*. Elle est aussi plus claire que *A m'entraîne* tout court, sans complément.  On **traîne derrière soi** (*drag*) mais on **entraîne avec soi** (*carry/sweep along*).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132118/discussion-between-jlliagre-and-lambie).

Comment: @Lambie C'est la définition d'Antidote, je l'ai écrit dans ma question.

Answer (score 5):

Si on emploie entraîner tout seul ça fait plutôt penser à un entraînement sportif.

> Mon ami a un cheval, il l’entraîne tous les jours.

Dans le sens où tu l'entends on s'attend à trouver un complément de manière ou de lieu, mais ce n'est pas obligatoire, sur la même page : ([France 3](https://france3-regions.francetvinfo.fr/normandie/seine-maritime/le-tracteur-entraine-un-cable-haute-tension-et-des-poteaux-telephoniques-2023897.html))

> Le tracteur entraîne un câble haute-tension et des poteaux téléphoniques

> ...le tracteur a entraîné avec lui un câble haute-tension de 20 000 volts et 3 poteaux électriques.

> Saint Nicolas a entraîné derrière lui les enfants et leurs parents pour un sympathique défilé dans les rues du village. ([Républicain Lorrain](https://www.republicain-lorrain.fr/edition-de-metz-agglo-et-orne/2017/12/06/saint-nicolas-tant-attendu))

> Une aventure collective longue et solide, qui a entraîné derrière elle un cortège d’intellectuel·les. ([Les Inrocks](https://www.lesinrocks.com/actu/ce-que-furent-les-annees-maos-dalain-badiou-natacha-michel-et-sylvain-lazarus-179866-08-09-2020/))

Tout dépend bien sûr du contexte, car parfois la précision peut s’avérer utile pour faciliter la lecture et éviter toute ambiguïté entre les deux sens de *entraîner*, ce qui, par exemple, pourrait être le cas dans cette phrase extraite de *De Gaulle, mon père* (Philippe De Gaulle) :

> – On a également contesté l'utilité de cette contre attaque...
> – Elle aurait pu être magistralement démontrée si mon père avait réussi à entraîner derrière lui les forces qui étaient en train de s'installer à l'arrière.

Mais on peut trouver d'autres préposions que avec ou derrière, selon le sens, plusieurs exemples dans le [Dictionnaire de l'Académie Française](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9E1912), dont :

> Le premier de cordée les entraîna dans sa chute.

> Cet homme d’affaires les a entraînés dans sa ruine.

Ce qui pourrait sembler redondant c'est la double précision, *avec* (derrière) ... *dans*... Cependant ça se peut se dire et on peut en trouver des exemples :

> Remarquons aussi que la pluie, en se précipitant du ciel sur la terre, entraîne avec elle dans sa chute une grande masse d'air... ([Les mondes revue hebdomadaire des sciences](https://books.google.fr/books?id=IrVZAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA352&lpg=PA352&dq=%22%20entraine%20avec%20elle%20dans%20sa%20chute%22&source=bl&ots=jBI0EVMt7o&sig=ACfU3U0ksrd57ySXH_Bi_wEMKyJspI1umg&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQmt2U6c_0AhUoy4UKHVu3BuYQ6AF6BAgaEAM#v=onepage&q=%22%20entraine%20avec%20elle%20dans%20sa%20chute%22&f=false))

> Après un long moment, la silhouette s'écarte prudemment, attrape le bras de la jeune fille et l'entraîne derrière elle dans la nuit. (Quatrième de couverture de *Chrétiens des catacombes* t.6)

Answer (score -2):

Cela semble exact, « entrainer avec soi » est plus ou moins redondant ; pour se rendre compte de cela il suffit de vérifier les définitions diverses du [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/entrainer)  (sens concrets et abstraits).

> 1. [Le suj. désigne une entité concr. animée de mouvement] Traîner **après soi**, déplacer en tirant **derrière soi**. Quatre remorqueurs décollèrent « l'Étoile-desmers » du quai, deux autres l'entraînèrent (Peisson, Parti Liverpool,1932, p. 29).

> b) [Le suj. désigne une pers. qui tombe] Emporter rapidement **avec soi** dans sa chute.

> B.− P. ext.
>
> 1. [Le suj. désigne gén. un cours d'eau, et parfois un phénomène naturel animé de mouvement] Emporter **avec soi**.

> 3. [Le suj. désigne une pers.] Emmener, conduire **avec soi**, en faisant parfois usage de la force.

> ex. : 1. [Le suj. désigne un abstr.]
> a) Amener, faire venir **à la suite**. Ce don [le sens du théâtre] en suppose plusieurs autres, et qu'il entraîne avec lui tout un cortège de facultés (Bourget, Nouv. essais psychol.,1885, p. 18)
> …exerce une influence prépondérante et entraîne les autres avec lui

Cependant, bien que ce soit un usage  courant au 19<sup>e</sup> siècle, il devient comparativement rare de nos jours, la raison de ce fait étant très possiblement l'impression de redondance qui s'en dégage.

[image]

[ngram 1](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=entraine+avec+lui&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Centraine%20avec%20lui%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Centraine%20avec%20lui%3B%2Cc0)
[image]

[image]

[ngram 2](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=entrainent+avec+eux&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Centrainent%20avec%20eux%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Centrainent%20avec%20eux%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

[image]

[ngram 3](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+entrain%C3%A9+avec+lui&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20entrain%C3%A9%20avec%20lui%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ca%20entrain%C3%A9%20avec%20lui%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

[image]

[ngram 4](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ont+entrain%C3%A9+avec+eux&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cont%20entrain%C3%A9%20avec%20eux%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

[image]

[ngram 5](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=entrainait+avec+lui&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Centrainait%20avec%20lui%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Centrainait%20avec%20lui%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

[image]

[ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=entrainaient+avec+eux&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Centrainaient%20avec%20eux%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Centrainaient%20avec%20eux%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

[image]

[ngram 7](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=entraina+avec+lui&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Centraina%20avec%20lui%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Centraina%20avec%20lui%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

[image]

[ngram 8](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=entrain%C3%A8rent+avec+eux&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Centrain%C3%A8rent%20avec%20eux%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Centrain%C3%A8rent%20avec%20eux%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

Vu le caractère redondant de cette construction, clairement mis en évidence par les définitions, et en considération du fait que dans le français moderne on en trouve une bien moins grande utilisation, on peut choisir d'épurer son langage et l'éviter, ce qui semble souhaitable, mais l'utiliser ne résulte pas en une véritable faute.

En ce qui concerne « derrière », qui est plus spécifique, on doit faire preuve de jugement : s'il y a un choix, « derrière » peut convenir, sinon, si la position est évidemment derrière l'ajout est plutôt superflu.

- Le sergeant les entraina à ses côtés et ils se lancèrent à l'assault.
- Le sergeant les entraina derrière lui et ils se lancèrent à l'assault.
- Le remorqueur entraina le paquebot à l'entrée du port.
- Dès qu'on l'eut attelé le cheval entraina le lourd chariot, mais péniblement.

Dans le cas d'un torrent qui entraine du bois arraché aux rives, « avec lui » semble hors de question (TLFi : 1. [Le suj. désigne gén. un cours d'eau, et parfois un phénomène naturel animé de mouvement] Emporter avec soi).

Comment: Ta réponse s'appuie sur des NGrams qui ne valent rien vu l'orthographe erronée utilisée.

Comment: @jlliagre Ma réponse s'appuie surtout sur le dictionaire, où la redondance est clairement démontrable plusieurs fois, et, de plus, avec l'ancienne orthographe, le résultat des ngrams est quasiment le même (déclin général presque toujours  très marqué).

Comment: Quasiment le même ?! Sur  les cinquante dernières années avec un lissage réglé sur 10 ans, on mesure une baisse pour *entra**î**ne avec lui* de **-20 %** et pour *entra**i**ne avec lui* de **-70 %**.

Comment: @jlliagre Néanmoins, il s'agit bien d'un déclin, et les définitions du dictionaire ne laisse aucun  doute, il ya a  une redondance incontestable.

Comment: @jlliagre Il faut aussi considérer que la période de cinquante années est bien trop courte ; le pic se trouve au 19e siècle.

Comment: Il n'y a pas redondance mais clarification. On peut très bien entraîner quelqu'un à faire quelque chose sans y prendre part soi-même (TLFi: *Par crainte d'entraîner maman au divorce*). On peut aussi discuter ce prétendu déclin. La forme *entraîna avec lui* par exemple, n'a jamais été d'après les NGrams aussi employée qu'aujourd'hui. De toute façon, la préposition la plus employée entre les formes verbales d'entraîner et *lui* est toujours *avec*, quelle que soit l'époque.